# Extracting scale factor and offsets from raster made with netcdf in R

Tags: scale, raster, netcdf

I have a raster file generated with the `raster` package from a netcdf file, and I need to extract the fillvalue, the scale factor and the offset. With the package `ncdf` I can extract those attributes with the next code:

```
fillvalue <- att.get.ncdf(ncdf,"tp","_FillValue")
scale <- att.get.ncdf(ncdf,"tp","scale_factor")
offset <- att.get.ncdf(ncdf,"tp","add_offset")
```

But with the `raster` package I don't know how to extract them, is it possible? Or do I have to extract them with `ncdf`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ncdf file to test, but if you read the file using `raster` and saved it using `raster`, I believe the below should work. If not try using `readGDAL` from the `rgdal` package to read the ncdf image.

```
library(raster)    
img <- raster(file_path)
scale <- gain(img)
offset <- offs(img)
fillvalue <- NAvalue(img)
```